# django -how to read uploaded csv file which one field contain '\n'

Tags: python, django, csv

I encountered a problem when I try to read a uploaded csv file which one field contains '\n' character. e.g. I have a csv file, its content like this:

- row 1: "one", "this is \nsample",
- row 2: "two", "this is also \nsample"

I can get the uploaded file in request.FILES successfully, but when I loop the file, the row will break down because '\n' character. My code is:

```
file = request.FILES.get('filename', None)
for line in file:
    if line:
        line = line.decode("utf-8")
        fields_set = list(csv.reader([line], skipinitialspace=True))[0]
```

In first loop, the content of variable 'line' is: `"one, this is"`. And in second loop, the variable'line' get the value "sample". but what I want is to get 'one, "this is \nsample"'.
Any help are appreciate, thanks in advance.

Answer (score 0):

You aren't using the csv.reader correctly. Use it in place of the file reader (the line *for line in file* line)

```
csvfile = request.FILES.get('filename', None)
readCSV = csv.reader(csvfile, delimiter=',')
for row in readCSV:
    print(row)
```

Comment: use csv.reader to read csvfile directly will pop up error "iterator should return strings, not bytes (did you open the file in text mode?)"

Comment: Make the iterator return strings then. The csv reader is not appropriately defined for this case since the Django InMemoryUploadedFile returns bytes, not strings. You need to do something like `f = csv.reader((x.decode('latin1') for x in csvfile.readlines()))` to convert the lines to strings.